# URL link gives dot instead of slash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

in my route.rb I have this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :cars do
    resource :payments
  end
end
```

However, in my destroy link for payments. the URL generated is

```
http://localhost:3000/cars/9/payments.11
```

Below is my code.

```
<% @car.payments.each do |p| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= p.date %></td>
    <td><%= p.profit %></td>
    <td><%= p.remark %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', car_payments_path(@car, @p) ,
           method: :delete,
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Please advice. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a pluralization error.
Try

```
cars_payment_path
```

instead of

```
car_payments_path
```

Comment: I have tried that, however it returns 
    undefined method `car_payment_path'

Comment: I tried both   undefined method `cars_payment_path'

Comment: Would also need to change `resource :payments` to `resources :payments` so that you can show a payment by id.

Answer (score 1):

To delete a payment in a car, the route should be a member route , call it like this:

```
car_payment_path(@car, @p)
```

`car_payments_path(..)` was a collection route of payments.

Suggest you to test at console like this:

```
app.car_payment_path(Car.first, Car.first.payments.first)
```